# SQL Server 2008 R2 : how to identify the login which has updated a table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

The data in one of the table has been updated by a user. I would need to identify the login used to amend the table and through which machine.identification of Either one of them would helpful

Comment: Most of my table have a `CreatedBy` column, so each row stores information about who created it.  (As well as `CreatedAt` for the date/time and `CreatedOn` for the server, if applicable.)

Comment: Thanks but I have not set any triggers on the table :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/21/sql-server-identify-last-user-access-of-table-using-t-sql-script/):

```
SELECT DB_NAME(ius.[database_id]) AS [Database],
OBJECT_NAME(ius.[object_id]) AS [TableName],
MAX(ius.[last_user_lookup]), 
MAX(ius.[last_user_scan]), 
MAX(ius.[last_user_seek]) 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS ius
WHERE ius.[database_id] = DB_ID()
AND ius.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('TableName')
GROUP BY ius.[database_id], ius.[object_id];
```

This will give you the last user access of the table.

Comment: There are multiple access to the table and multiple updates happened after the update I am looking for.